# Can my router communicate with local devices without an ISP?

Tags: router

I want my PC to act as the server and other devices connected to the router on the wifi as the hosts. I think that the realization of the server by an application is possible which is installed on the remote device. But would the router route the packages that are sent to it without an ISP ?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand fully, but if you have a router with devices connected to it and no internet (WAN port) then the devices can still communicate with each other. I have done this.

Comment: Any router can manage a lan,  that's their purpose after all,  not communicating with the wan.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia not entirely correct. A router's job is to manage communication between the switch and the WAN port. But yes, usually people use the switch part, and that is what this question is actually about. The switch only cares about the lan ports and wifi.

Comment: @LPChip The "thing" that deals with the ISP part, technically, isn't the router (but is quite common in everyday language to call a "router + AP + modem or whatever" combo simply a "router"). Strictly speaking the router creates routes,  that's it.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia if you ask anyone what a router is, they will point at the entire device. What sets a router apart from any other device? The fact that it is an all-in-one package. Technically speaking the router routes packages through NAT Translation which means from WAN to LAN and back. The router does not do LAN only, so technically speaking the router DOES the part with dealing with the ISP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A router is a device that creates a new internal network, and bridges that with an external network. The ISP is connected to the WAN port, and all devices on the internal network are either connected through the LAN ports, or through WIFI.

Because of this, the ISP cannot access your devices in the internal network unless you open specific ports. Regardless of whether you open ports or not, all devices on the internal network can access each other without restrictions.

So if you setup a server, local devices will communicate with it even if you unplug the WAN port.

Keep in mind, that you do use the local ip addresses, and not your public WAN IP Address. If your router does not support a loopback connection, it will not even work regardless on how you setup the router, but with local ip addresses, it will always work.

If you want to make certain services of your server accessible to the internet, then you also need to setup port forwarding rules so the router knows where to forward the traffic to.

So yes, the router will work without an ISP because you are only using the switch part of a router.